# Bootstrap 4 navbar stick on top of carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, navbar

Having a little problem with positioning of my navbar. I want to place my navbar stick on the top of carousel. Not over carousel but in carousel, like captions, but on all sliders. So when scrolling page navbar and carousel will equal hidden.

Can't find it in documentation.

Trying to place whole < nav > into carousel but I think this is bad way.

Maybe there is some class like "fixed-top" and where should I put it ?

"navbar-static-top" also not working or maybe I put in wrong place ?

Here is navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon bg-danger"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto nav-fill w-100">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

And here carousel:

```
<div id="carousel-fade" class="carousel carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-fade" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-fade" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-fade" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" role="listbox">
  <div class="carousel-item embed-responsive-item active">
    <img src="slider1-2-1916x968.jpg" alt="First slide image" class="img-fluid">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>First slide Heading</h3>
      <p>First slide Caption</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel-item embed-responsive-item">
    <img src="slider2-2-1916x968.jpg" alt="Second slide image" class="img-fluid">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Second slide Heading</h3>
      <p>Second slide Caption</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel-item embed-responsive-item">
    <img src="slider3-3-1916x968.jpg" alt="Third slide image" class="img-fluid">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Third slide Heading</h3>
      <p>Third slide Caption</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-fade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-fade" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with very simple code.

just add

style="z-index:10;"

to navbar.

done!